# random number dont working after many try

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hello i want to make a simple function to get random number between two numbers , can any one help me ?

I try to use some defult function on type script but its not working...

**Here my try :**

```js
function randomNumber(min: number, max: number): number {
  return Math.random() * (max + min);
}
```

any one can help ?

Answer (score 0):

This function will reutrn you random number between two numbers (min - max) :

```
function getRandomNumber(min: number, max: number): number {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

For example :

```
getRandomNumber (1,100); // Random number between 1-100
getRandomNumber (200,500); // Random number between 200-500
```